# Search criteria involving collection property

Tags: grails

Is it possible to define a search criteria on an object which has a collection property and the criteria deals with the contents of the collection property? For example say I have a `class Car` which has a `List` property called `components` which looks like:

```
components = ['seats', 'steering wheel', 'trunk']
```

now how would I go about defining a search criteria that would find all cars that have a 'trunk'?

something like:

```
'in' ('components', 'trunk')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `GORM` and it's `criteria-queries`, then

```
'in' [ 'aaa', 'trunk' ]
```

should do.

Show your domain class also

Comment: What is 'aaa'? I did notice that you are using square brackets is that how you tell GORM to check domain's collections instead of domain's non-collection properties as we usually deal with in criteria?

Comment: do you use mongo? if yes, use it's "native" querying capability

Comment: the `sql-based` GORM doesn't let you use primitive collections that easily

Comment: By "native" for mongo do you mean like gmongo?

Comment: there's no other alternatives to mongo-gorm + gmongo. So, if you have a collection in your domain class, you can query it by:
`Car.collection.find( components:[ $in:'trunk' ] )`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I could use code like that within Grails. Where can I see more such examples?

Comment: the plugin ref-doc states it in `Low-level API` section. For code examples see the http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/ . It's full of useful example queries and you can take them into your grails code almost unchanged